# I´ve a problem with the BottomNavigationBar in Flutter . BottomNavigationBarItem: title is not working and there is error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBF7s.png)this is the error occur.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.home,
      ),
      title: Text(
        'Home',
      ),
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.message,
      ),
      title: Text(
        'Messages',
      ),
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.person,
      ),
      title: Text(
        'Profile',
      ),
    ),
  ],

),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ2Fk.png) error code snippets

help for solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bro there's not parameter with name 'title' in the BottomNavigationBarItem. you need to use label for giving the text in the BottomNavigationBarItem widget and it aspects string directly.

So the updated code would look like this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.home,
          ),
          label: 'Home',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.message,
        ),
        label: 'Messages',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.person,
        ),
        label: 'Profile',
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that there is no property `title` in the `BottomNavigationBarItem`, instead use `label`

also the error in the first picture says, that label is equal to `null`

Comment: when i use label instead of title ,there is error friend

Comment: same answer as where you wrote that it is working, my friend

Answer (score 0):

You should use label instead of title

[image: BottomNavigationBarItem]

[image: The label]

Comment: it doesnt work friend

Comment: The solution in my answer is the same as the pixel's solution. Are you sure?. I just showed the inside of the BottomNavigationBarItem class